# How to Generate FY from Date Column In Db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have one Column In my  Db2 table in which I have data in 'YYYYMMDD' format. I need to Create Financial Year from this column,so If month is in Jan,Feb or March then in Fy I need to generate as Prev year '-' current year else current year '-' next Year.

In My source Table I have MTH_YR column as '20210101'.I am Able to generate date from this column as 2021-01-01 now from this column i need to genarate Fy as 2020-2021
I am writing below Query

```
    select substring(MTH_YR, 1, 4) || '-' || substring(MTH_YR, 5, 2) || '-' || 
    substring(MTH_YR, 7, 2)  as date_format,
    CASE WHEN month(to_date(date_format)) IN (01,02,03) THEN 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(date_format))-1,'-'),substr(year(to_date(date_format)),3,4)) 
    ELSE 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(date_format)),'-'),SUBSTR(year(to_date(date_format))+1,3,4))
    end as FY from schemaname.Tablename;
```

But Getting Below Error.

```
    "FY" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

Can someone Please Guide me How should I Implement the same.

Comment: You cannot reference column aliases, specifically `date_format` in the same select list.

Comment: Are you storing the date as a string rather than as a `date`?  If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you stored your date as a *date*, you would simply subtract 3 months and take the year:

```
select year(add_months(date_col, -3)) as fiscal_year
```

You can make this a string representation if you prefer:

```
select year(add_months(date_col, -3)) || '-' || (year(add_months(date_col, -3)) + 1)
```

If your date is not stored as a date, you should *fix the data*.  But absent that, you can convert it in the expression.